# AlarmManager skips alarms set using set() / setExact() in a 48hrs+ cycle

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

In an app I have to regularly sync data to a server which happens at a fixed interval (mostly) of 5mins.

I am using `set()` / `setExact()` depending upon if `Build API >= 19`. Now, for most of the time the alarm gets fired and does it's job but intermittently (even during daytime) the alarm isn't getting fired.

The alarm manager is passed a `pendingIntent` for an `IntentService` which does the sync work.

And in `onHandleIntent` I am also running my `setSchedule()` which in turn sets an alarm to get fired after 5 mins(same as above^).

Using Alarm Type of `RTC_WAKEUP` (until now; I've recently changed it to `elasped realtime + wakeup` and waiting on for some test results)and the `HTTP connection` and `socket timeout` of 30secs each. The device was not restarted in between the 48hrs+ (as a sample case) duration as I don't miss any captured data it's just that the sync alarm skips somehow.

I am starting to doubt if this is a `wakelock` issue :|

Has anyone faced any problem with Kitkat's `setExact()` ? AFAIK, the way it is (except for using the RTC/elasped realtime change) the current way shouldn't be skipping on the alarms.